# I need to close a pop-up window after some period of time

Tags: javascript

I need to close the pop-window which is triggered from 3rd party site after some time passes.
I know we can close the pop-up using `setTimeout("self.close()",5000)` in body of the page, but the pop-up is triggering from other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can control windows that are opened from a different session. Pretty sure that would be a big security hole if you could.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pop;
    function cl() {
        form1.elements["wt"].value=65;
        pop.close();
    }

    function open_win() 
    {
        pop = window.open("loading_page.html",'popUpWindow','height=200,width=150,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,position=center,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes',align="center"); 
        setTimeout("cl()",5000);
    }
</script>
```

I used the `cl()` to populate a textfield after 5 seconds having `form` name  as   `form1` and `textfield` name as `wt`.

Comment: This is not what has been asked for. Imagine you have opened one page which does the `open()` part, but an independent page for the `close()` part.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `close` method of the new window.

```
function() { // It is a popup, so obviously you need to call this from a user triggered event and not page load
    var pop = window.open('http://example.com');
    var close = function() {
        pop.close();
    };
    setTimeout(close, 2000);
}
```